# Why am I not receiving the value of the name, phone, & email fields on my email in PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm not receiving any values from the name, phone, & email field from HTML. What am I doing wrong?

PHP code:

```
<?php   
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
// Below line sends the form to the email address listed
    $to = 'Coach Dave <coachdaveboxing@gmail.com>'; 
    $subject = 'Client Profile';    
}

$message .= 'Name: ' . $_POST['name'] . "\r\n\r\n";
$message .= 'Phone: ' . $_POST['phone'] . "\r\n\r\n";
$message .= 'Email: ' . $_POST['email'];


// Validate Client's Name, Phone, & Email
if (!empty($name) || !empty($phone)) {
    echo "Name, phone number, and email are required.";
    exit;
}

$body = 'This is the body of the email message.';   
$headers = "From: coachdaveboxing.com\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8';

$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

if ($email) {
   $headers .= "\r\nReply-To: $email";
}

$success = mail($to, $subject, $message, 
           $headers, '-fcoachdaveboxing@gmail.com');
?>

<center>
<body style="margin-top: 50px; 
      margin-left: 250px;
      color: black;
      padding: 35px; 
      width: 650px;
      height: 140px;
      background: #F7F5EF;
      border-color: #B72424;
      border-width: 15px;
      border-style: outset;">

<?php if (isset($success) && $success) { ?>
<h1>Thank you contacting Coach Dave.<br/></h1>
<h2>enter code hereYour form was successfully submitted.<br/>
    Coach Dave will contact you within 24 hours.<h2>    
<?php } else { ?>
<h1>Oops!</h1>
Sorry, there was a problem sending your message.
<?php } ?>
</body></center>
```

Here is the HTML code and I'm trying to get the value of name, phone & email field send to my email address:

============TEXTBOX FOR NAME, PHONE,& EMAIL ==============

```
  <form method="post" action="acknowledge.php">

    <div id="nameBox" align="center">
      <div class="row">
        <label for="name"> Name:&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" value="" size="40"> </br>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
        <label for="phone"> Phone:&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="tel" id="phone" value="" size="40"> </br>
      </div>

      <div class="row"> 
        <label for="email"> Email:&nbsp;</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" value="" size="40"> </br>
      </div>
    </div> <!-- end #nameBox -->
```

Answer (score 3):

You forgot the name attributes for your form fields. Without them no value is submiited.

```
<div id="nameBox" align="center">
  <div class="row">
    <label for="name"> Name:&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="" size="40"> </br>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <label for="phone"> Phone:&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="tel" name="phone" id="phone" value="" size="40"> </br>
  </div>

  <div class="row"> 
    <label for="email"> Email:&nbsp;</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" value="" size="40"> </br>
  </div>
</div> <!-- end #nameBox -->
```

Comment: I tried putting values, but I still don't get any values.

Comment: You should be. Open the page in your browser and verify you see them in your source code. Then, at the top of your page, put `var_dump($_POST);` and see if they are there.

Comment: Am I putting  var_dump($_POST); at the php code? on top of <?php

Comment: Put it right after `if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {`. You can learn more about Markdown [here](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: After putting your code, it gives the following:     array(6) { ["month"]=> string(12) "- Location -" ["day"]=> string(7) "- Day -" ["year"]=> string(8) "- Year -" ["Day"]=> string(7) "- Day -" ["Time"]=> string(8) "- Time -" ["submit"]=> string(11) "Submit Form" }

Comment: Do you have a submit button?

Comment: Clearly the changes have not made their way to your form. There is a disconnect somewhere. Unfortunately I can't troubleshoot that from here. You need to figure out why your updated form is not being used in your sure. Once it is your issue will go away.

Comment: I have a submit button. So is it on the HTML side or the PHP side?